# automapper mapping certain bool property based on enum value

Tags: c#, automapper

The destination class has a list of bools. The DTO that gets mapped to the destination class has 1 enum property. depending on what the enum is some of the bools in the destination class should be set. how to achieve it in automapper? 
.ForMember() won't work because i would have to do enum logic check for each of the bool property.
I want to do a mapping `this.CreateMap<DestinationDTO, Destination>()` where depending on what the payout is Property1 or Property2 or Property3 gets set.

See below:

```
public class Destination
{
  public bool? Property1{get; set;}
  public bool? Property2{get; set;}
  public bool? Property3{get;set;}
}

public class DestinationDTO
{
   public Enum Payout{get; set;}
}
public Enum Payout
{
  Proration = 1,
  Recurrent = 2,
  Lumpsum = 3
}
```

If the DestinationDTO.Payout == Payout.Proration, I want to set Destination entity class's Property1 to be true, similarly depending on what payout it is, I might want to set another Property in the entity class. Can I do this in automapper when mapping the DestinationDTO to Destination entity class?

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Before-and-after-map-actions.html

Comment: We need to see code to understand what you're asking.

Comment: edited the question and added a model code to provide a context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `ForMember` expressions:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DestinationDTO, Destination>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Property1,
            m => m.MapFrom(d => d.Payout == Payout.Proration ? true : default(bool?)))
        .ForMember(d => d.Property2,
            m => m.MapFrom(d => d.Payout == Payout.Recurrent ? true : default(bool?)))
        .ForMember(d => d.Property3,
            m => m.MapFrom(d => d.Payout == Payout.Lumpsum ? true : default(bool?)));
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var dtos = new[]
{
    new DestinationDTO { Payout = Payout.Proration },
    new DestinationDTO { Payout = Payout.Recurrent },
    new DestinationDTO { Payout = Payout.Lumpsum },
};

var destinations = dtos.Select(d => mapper.Map<Destination>(d));
```

Off-topic: I'd prefer non-nullable booleans. Then you can remove the `? true : default(bool?)` parts and a `Destination` still tells the truth in all of its properties.